# Adding system references to .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Okay, this is (or at least *should* be) a stupid question: How do I add a reference to a system assembly in .NET Core projects?

I have a .NET Core class library. If I right click on *Dependencies*, there is still a *Add Reference...* command, but it only allows me to add references to my other projects. There is now an *SDK* section, but right clicking there provides no option to add new references.

[image: Dependencies options drop down with Add Reference.. option]

This was so straight forward before. I don't understand why this has changed or how I now add a reference to something like *Microsoft.Win32.Registry*. (My understanding is I need a NuGet package for this assembly, but my question still stands about adding system references.)

Comment: What about the Microsoft.Win32.Registry NuGet package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: Yes, I found some documentation for that. And so I understand the one I want to add may not be on my system. But I'm still confused about how to add a system reference that's on my system.

Comment: When I click Add Reference... on a new .NET Core Class Library project, I can click on a Browse... button and select a DLL. Do you not see that?

Comment: What is the system assembly you are trying to reference? Do you mean "System.Web" or something like that?

Comment: @Nyra: I indicated which assembly I want in the question. But that's not really the point because my question applies to any assembly, also explained in my question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Yes. And I assume I can use that option to search around my entire hard drive to find the file and then research around to see if that is the one I need. However, with non-.NET-Core projects, the Browse feature includes an Assemblies section, which lists all the Microsoft assemblies. I'm at a loss as to why that's been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your system contains this assembly it does not gurantee that other systems also contain it. .Net Core is about cross platform so I do not think there is this assembly in Linux system. So you should distribute not only your code but some of "system" dll as well. And it is easier to update only one nuget package for adding new functionality, bug-fixing, etc than update all framework.

Comment: Microsoft says .NET Core is the future, single version of .NET. That's why I'm porting to it. I could care less about Linux or to avoid using parts of the operating system I'm actually running on. Also, when you compile your end application, it includes the assemblies that it needs to run.